# ulimit overrides sysctl

Tags: ulimit

I set sysctl fs.file-max = 4500000. However, ulimit still shows open files (-n) 1024

I understand that both values point to the max open file descriptors. How do I make ulmit respect the sysctl value?

Is there any documentation on the meanings of the various values of sysctl?

Answer (score 1):

if what you are looking for is a permanent set to the ulimit, you'll want to add the line

ulimit -n 4500000

to /etc/profile (source /etc/profile afterwards to see change).

As for finding the meaning of systctl, you can find detailed information here:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/

Comment: Not quite.  You are better off setting the value in /etc/security/limits.conf (depending on distro).  While setting it in /etc/profile will work, the next sysadmin to come after you won't be expecting it there.

Comment: I've tried setting in /etc/security/limits.conf but could not get ulimit -n to return what I set in the file. Is there an extra step I was missing?

Comment: Did you log out and log back in?  The values in limits.conf are only applied during new logins.

Comment: i did logout and log back in. I'll take a look at it again though.  Thanks for your help!